# How to add Position Fixed on specific Div and then remove that class on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, fixed

Here is the Jsfiddle i am working on 
https://jsfiddle.net/farooqshad/jbdczk10/10/

Basically i want to add a class on scroll to specific div and then remove that class .

Here is my javascript

```js
var YourDiv = $(".mainwrapper");
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log(scroll);
  if (scroll >= YourDiv.offset().top - 10) {
    YourDiv.addClass('fixed');
    console.log("fixed");
  } else {
    YourDiv.removeClass('fixed');
    console.log("Not Fixed");
  }
});
```

Comment: What is not working? when i run your jsfiddle it adds the class and removes it again

Comment: @Sofyan Thayf after that mainwrapper div i want to remove the class the else condition is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

farooq try this solution

```
var YourDiv = $(".mainwrapper");
var foo=$(".footer1")
$(window).scroll(function () {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll >= YourDiv.offset().top - 10 && scroll<=foo.offset().top - 10) {
    YourDiv.addClass('fixed');
}
else
{
    YourDiv.removeClass('fixed');
}
});
```

and let me know if don't works
this is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6rs3endu/1/)

Comment: Thanks its working but i also need to add a class if page refresh and scroll is on that section